# How to create a desktop shortcut to a Onedrive file

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013, onedrive

I would like to create a shortcut on my desktop to an Excel file located on OneDrive and having it open in Excel. (I'm using Windows7 and Office 2013)

Within Excel, I have retrieved the path to file (https://d.docs.live.net/cxxxxxxxcexxxxx/Documents/myfile.xlsx). But if I create a shortcut with Url it opens the file within my Browser and not within Excel.

The creation of a shortcut forcing the usage of Excel ("excel https://d.docs.live.net/cxxxxxxxcexxxxx/Documents/myfile.xlsx") fails at "The path does not exist".

Any other idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `http://...` shortcut, I used a shortcut starting with `\\d.docs.live.net@SSL\DavWWWRoot\cxxxxxxxcexxxxx/Documents/myfile.xlsx`,
and it opens the file directly in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hacking internal paths, go native way referring to your locally stored synced copy of the OneDrive file:

1. In Windows Explorer, open your **OneDrive** Personal Folder (typically it has a cloud icon)
2. Right-click your file
3. Select command **Send to** > **Desktop (create shortcut)**

This way, you care only about your local copy of the file and you let OneDrive to do the sync with cloud version of the file – so you no longer need to use paths referring to cloud by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the full path to Excel in your shortcut rather than just 'excel'.

for example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe" "https://d.docs.live.net/cxxxxxxxcexxxxx/Documents/myfile.xlsx"
```

(path will vary depending on your version of Office, you'll need to look through Program Files yourself and find which path is correct)

Answer (score 0):

You can **right click on Excel in your taskbar**, it doesn't work from the start menu, and you'll have the option to **pin or select recently used files** which will take them from the local cache without having to find the file and create a shorcut through drag and drop.  This will allow you to have one icon with access to multiple files.

The other option is to **right click your desktop** and **select New then Create new shortcut** which will open a dialogue asking you to **browse for the file.  Select OneDrive** from the "filelist" and **then the specific directory and file then click next**.  **Give your shortcut a name and click Finish.**  This will insure you are getting the most current data from the cloud unlike using your local cache which if your having multiple users may not be up to date.

Answer (score -1):

how stupid is Microsoft? Millions of users want to work in privacy offline: the Wizards of Redmond want us captured by bandwidth and online editing. Try that with a 200+ page document

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1092034)